# PHP how to fail a request

Tags: php

Honestly, I don't know a lot about PHP but I think what I need to do is relatively simple.

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ in an iOS app. I simply need to add code to my PHP script that will make the request fail, therefore calling the requestFailed delegate method of ASI. I would assume this is with an HTTP Response code but everything I've tried results int he request succeeding. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I don't really know PHP.

I've tried

```
trigger_error("error yo", E_USER_ERROR);
die;
```

As well as

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
die;
```

Comment: I looked around in the code a bit but was rather lost.  My guess is that the definition of a "failed request" is one that times out.

Comment: Why don't you try accessing a page that doesn't exist to see if that handles failure correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this

```
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
```

Turns out ASI doesn't handle most HTTP Response codes except authentication and moved.

Answer (score 1):

trigger_error will not output headers. header() will.

But, header() will only work if and when there is no output already sent to the browser. Your best bet is to just access the URL directly in your browser to make sure things are working. Also, make sure in your php.ini configuration file, that display_errors is on. Some PHP distributions have this turned off by default.

Comment: `display_errors` is not required for a 4xx or 5xx error code, and should not be enabled in production environments, let you disclose potentially sensitive information to would-be script kiddies.